# Error setting up openocd in windows mysys for esp32

Tags: esp32, openocd

Hi i am trying to set up Openocd in windows 10 by following https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.1/api-guides/jtag-debugging/building-openocd-windows.html from espressif documentation page.

I am struck with ./bootstrap process error.

[image: Mysys esp32 openocd error]

How to solve this?

Comment: Hi yogeshwaran, would you mind copying and pasting the error message as text?

Answer (score 0):

I installed libtool using pacman then it worked